# how to get only one column from a entire table using foreign key in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project. where I need to map the fields using foreign key.

how to add only one field instead of whole table using foreign key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the `__str__` method to specify how it should show the `Developer` object:

```
class Developers(models.Model):
    # …
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Developer_Name
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Developer` instead of <s>`Developers`</s>.

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `developer_name` instead of <s>`Developer_Name`</s>.

Comment: thanks @willem. it worked. But i have another question. like if i want to put some condition like if Role is 11 then only devloper_name will show. how to make that condition in my models ? can you help me in that please?

Comment: @RikaDas: you can work with [**`limit_choices_to=...`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to).

Comment: Hey @Willem can you please help me in this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67916754/on-click-of-table-row-i-want-to-view-the-data-of-that-row-as-a-modal-popup-in-dj?noredirect=1#comment120044882_67916754